# Flutter iOS: Update macOS and to Xcode 15 and it broke Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, xcode15

I have the latest Flutter SDK and the latest CocoaPods: **1.14.3**.

When I run `flutter build ios`, I get this:

```
Xcode build done.                                           200.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _pb_decode
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _pb_decode_varint
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _pb_encode
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _pb_encode_string
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _pb_encode_submessage
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _pb_encode_tag_for_field
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _pb_encode_varint
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _pb_istream_from_buffer
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _pb_ostream_from_buffer
Error (Xcode): Undefined symbol: _pb_read
Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Encountered error while building for device.
```

Added a `protobuf` package hoping that this would do it and that did not do it.
I also did this in PodFile:

```
platform :ios, '13.0' and config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
platform :ios, '14.0' and config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
platform :ios, '15.0' and config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '15.0'
```

I get the same result regardless of each.

I also set other link flags add "-ld64